# Coloring quote from quotchap

Tags: quotchap

I want to use the `quotchap` package to include quotes on every chapter. But is there a way to change the text-color of the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{quotchap}

\begin{document}

\begin{savequote}[45mm]
\color{red}
---When shall we three meet again
in thunder, lightning, or in rain?
---When the hurlyburly's done,
when the battle's lost and won.
\qauthor{Shakespeare, Macbeth}
Cookies! Give me some cookies!
\qauthor{Cookie Monster}
\end{savequote}
\chapter{Classic Sesame Street}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a way. You can use \textcolor[color]{your text}. Hope this helps.

Comment: Apparently, your answer is not specific to the question.